# Magento 1.9 not able to save upsell/related/cross sell products

Tags: php, mysql, magento

When I save a new product or edit an existing product in Magento everything saves correctly except upsell/related/cross sell products. Product is being saved with no errors. If I hit edit again the upsell product I selected before wasn't saved.

Submission completes with no errors (magento, php, mysql logs) no data from upsell,related or crosssell tabs is being saved.

I have run the magento database checker (corrupt vs reference) and it returned no errors. Have also run magento permission checker, still no joy. Have also disabled extensions.

Any ideas where I might look next? Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be seeking general support with Magneto, not assistance with developing against it.

Answer (score 6):

It turned out to be a conflict with the extension BL_CustomGrid.
Once this was disabled everything worked fine.

Comment: As a reference, here is a link to the respective bug report: https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids/issues/222

Answer (score 0):

We solved it by updating `max_input_vars` value from 1000 to 5000 in PHP configuration.